# Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise<any>' Error in @ionic-native/background-geolocation plugin

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am trying to implement background geolocation capturing for my application but I am getting error Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise'. Here is my code.
app.module.ts

```
import { BackgroundGeolocation } from '@ionic-native/background-geolocation/ngx';

 providers: [
    BackgroundGeolocation,
    ],
```

liveLocation.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BackgroundGeolocation, BackgroundGeolocationConfig, BackgroundGeolocationResponse }
 from '@ionic-native/background-geolocation/ngx';

const config: BackgroundGeolocationConfig = {
  desiredAccuracy: 10,
  stationaryRadius: 20,
  distanceFilter: 30,
  debug: true, //  enable this hear sounds for background-geolocation life-cycle.
  stopOnTerminate: false, // enable this to clear background location settings when the app terminates
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})


export class LiveLocationService {

  constructor(private backgroundGeolocation: BackgroundGeolocation) { }

  LiveLocationCapturing(){

    this.backgroundGeolocation.configure(config)
  .subscribe((location: BackgroundGeolocationResponse) => {

    console.log(location);


  });

  }
}
```

error:

```
  ERROR in src/app/service/liveLocation/live-location.service.ts(25,4): error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise<any>'.
```

Comment: Replace `subscribe` with `then`, and consider learning about RxJS and JS promises before using frameworks.

Comment: its not giving any option for then

Comment: you can only subscribe to observable. For promises you will require .then operator to resolve them.

Comment: @nitish if you don't have intellisense for `then`, then it means you have the wrong definition files. But doing as said will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Promise, it's `.then()`.
With Observable, you're right, it's `.subscribe()`

Comment: please check this plugin @ionic-native/background-geolocation